# Updating attribute of jQuery object has no effect

Tags: jquery, dom, coffeescript

I'm writing a function which iterates through a DOM and adds spaces to the beginning of nodes. Here's what it looks like:

```
$ = require 'jquery'

addSpaces = (node, noSpace=true) ->
  for child in ($ node).prop('childNodes')
    # nodeType of 3 means a text node
    if child.nodeType is 3
      if child.textContent
        child.textContent = child.textContent.trim()
        if child.textContent[0] not in [',', '.', ':', ';', ')']
          if noSpace then noSpace = false
          else 
            console.log "About to add a space, text is '#{child.textContent}'"
            child.textContent = ' ' + child.textContent
            console.log "Added a space, now text is '#{child.textContent}'"
    # nodeType of 1 means a DOM element, recurse down
    else if child.nodeType is 1
      addSpaces child, noSpace

input = "<foo><bar>I<baz>need</baz><qux>some</qux>spaces</bar></foo>"

node = $ input

console.log node.prop 'outerHTML'
addSpaces node
console.log node.prop 'outerHTML'
```

Running this gives

```
> coffee spaces.coffee
<foo><bar>I<baz>need</baz><qux>some</qux>spaces</bar></foo>
About to add a space, text is 'need'
Added a space, now text is 'need'
About to add a space, text is 'some'
Added a space, now text is 'some'
About to add a space, text is 'spaces'
Added a space, now text is 'spaces'
<foo><bar>I<baz>need</baz><qux>some</qux>spaces</bar></foo>
```

So, we can see that the line `child.textContent = ' ' + child.textContent` has no effect: the spaces don't get added (even within the scope of that one function). What's going on here? I'm new to jQuery, and I'm guessing it has something to do with that, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to use `nodeValue` instead of `textContent`:

```
$ = require 'jquery'

addSpaces = (node, noSpace=true) ->
  for child in ($ node).prop('childNodes')
    # nodeType of 3 means a text node
    if child.nodeType is 3
      if child.nodeValue
        child.nodeValue = child.textContent.trim()
        if child.nodeValue[0] not in [',', '.', ':', ';', ')']
          if noSpace then noSpace = false
          else 
            console.log "About to add a space, text is '#{child.nodeValue}'"
            child.nodeValue = ' ' + child.nodeValue
            console.log "Added a space, now text is '#{child.nodeValue}'"
    # nodeType of 1 means a DOM element, recurse down
    else if child.nodeType is 1
      addSpaces child, noSpace

input = "<foo><bar>I<baz>need</baz><qux>some</qux>spaces</bar></foo>"

node = $ input

console.log node.prop 'outerHTML'
addSpaces node
console.log node.prop 'outerHTML'
```